# Can't compare file content

Tags: php, arrays, file, compare

I have a problem, and I can't solve it. The first thing I have done is reading a file and storing it in an array. Then I took the first line of the file and compared it, and it **should** be `true`, but it gives `false`. I have tried to echo the line and saw that it is **exactly** the same, but it still says false. Why?

Here's my code:

```
//Store's the file content in a array.
$file = file($_SESSION['filecontent']);

if($file[0] == '------Compare_this------'){
    //Done
}else{
    //It dosn't work...
}
```

Comment: have u done print_r($file) ?

Comment: if (trim($file[0] == "------Compare_this------') { will help?

Comment: As [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) says, the function `file()` *returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, **with the newline still attached**.* You need to strip the newline and the comparison will succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `file()` function includes new line character by default. You can easily change that behavior by putting `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag as a second argument, like this:

```
$file = file($_SESSION['filecontent'], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: If it doesn't, it might be file encoding issue. But I believe it will work.